# Yii2 Issue upload pdf file with whitespace inside

Tags: php, yii2

I Have issue when try to upload pdf file with whitespace in name of file. There are no issue with image files and pdf files without white space.

```
UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'img_name')
```

returns only file name if pdf file has whitespace.

I var_dump $_FILES, here is what it returns:

with whitespace:

```
array (size=1)
  'ModelName' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => 
        array (size=1)
          'img_name' => string 'File Name with whitespace.pdf' (length=27)
      'type' => 
        array (size=1)
          'img_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => 
        array (size=1)
          'img_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => 
        array (size=1)
          'img_name' => int 1
      'size' => 
        array (size=1)
          'img_name' => int 0
```

without whitespace:

```
array (size=1)
  'ModelName' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => 
        array (size=1)
          'img_name' => string 'file-name-of-pdf.pdf' (length=17)
      'type' => 
        array (size=1)
          'img_name' => string 'application/pdf' (length=15)
      'tmp_name' => 
        array (size=1)
          'img_name' => string '/private/var/tmp/phpMpcLyS' (length=26)
      'error' => 
        array (size=1)
          'img_name' => int 0
      'size' => 
        array (size=1)
          'img_name' => int 1844625
```

Anybody had same issue and how I can solve this?

Comment: You can just use `preg_replace` to swap all whitespaces with `-`..

Comment: Jorgen,  where you advice to use it? I thing in this case I have to use something in user side with JS. I think my main issue that php not store in 'tmp_name'. And I don't know if it's Yii or PHP issue.

Comment: try to `$model->img_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $model->img_name);` in your action right after the POST is loaded.

Comment: Jorgen, If you will look above dumped information my issue is that, I don't have temp file so I can't move file for correct location. I can store name in DB, issue is that I can't load file physically to according folder.

Comment: Okey. Can you update your question with the controller action code? I'll have a look at it later

Comment: Jorgen, it's not Controller related issue. it's between when form submitted and receiving in Controller. Above information ($_FILES global variable) was recorded right after $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) condition checked in Controller. Issue that there are no php temporary name for file in $_FILES variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found reason, Issue was with php max upload size limitation. It was changed in my mac when I upgrade to new php 5 version.

By coincidence name containing whitespace were big size pdf files )).

I just added `php_value upload_max_filesize 30M` line to .htaccess